# Why Android View class has 'outValues style' getters for handful of properties?

Tags: android, android-view

You can get some View properties like `height`, `alpha`, `id`, `matrix`,  `drawingTime` or `elevation` using standard getters (like `getHeight()`, `getAlpha()`, `getId()`...).

But then, you have some of the View's properties (most of them with `Point` or `Rect` return type) like `locationInWindow`, `globalVisibleRect`, `locationInScreen`, `drawingRect`, `drawingCache` hidden under getters that are forcing you to create returning objects beforehand with empty constructor, and pass those objects as a getter parameter so that data is being 'saved' to them.

Example of the getter for `globalVisibleRect`:

```
public final boolean getGlobalVisibleRect(Rect r)
```

forces you to do something like this (Kotlin):

```
val rect = Rect()
getGlobalVisibleRect(rect)
doSomeStuffWithRect(rect)
```

It's not really consistent, nor it is debuggable in realtime with Expressions tab in Android Studio and it's just cumbersome, really.

Why is it done that way? I see some of the methods returning false boolean value if the View is not visible, thus you know that returned data is invalid, but shouldn't it be solved with returning null value, if the method already knows that it produced unusable information? On the other hand, `getLocationOnScreen` returns void and has no additional parameters, so I can't really understand why would you complicate stuff that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it done that way?

To encourage reuse of objects, such as via an object pool. Creating a zillion `Rect` instances and having GC clean them up is inefficient, particularly on 2006-era devices. Creating and collecting a zillion `Rect` instances also fragments the heap, which is still a problem for pre-Android 8.0 devices, though Android 5.0's changes helped somewhat.

Comment: That's a very interesting point, although I've never seen developers using object pool for pooling Views' properties. Will do a little read on heap fragmentation, thanks!

Comment: @PrzemyslawJablonski: Bear in mind that app developers are not the primary consumers of methods like `getGlobalVisibleRect()`. The framework is, in the form of `View`, `ViewGroup`, and kin.